# Get bitmap / thumbnail from a streaming video with format like .mp4, .3gp in Android?

Tags: android, video, bitmap, youtube, ffmpeg

I am working on ListView which on item click redirecting to a video link.
I explain my problem :

I have three types of videos :

- Youtube
- Dailymotion
- Other formats from streaming video like this one : [Video Link](http://download.wavetlan.com//SVV//Media//HTTP//MP4//ConvertedFiles//MediaCoder//MediaCoder_test3_1m10s_MPEG4SP_VBR_516kbps_320x240_25fps_MPEG1Layer3_CBR_320kbps_Stereo_44100Hz.mp4)

I am trying to get thumbnail to get it in my ImageView from my item of my ListView. I encoutered a problem, I get Youtube thumbnail, Dailymotion thumbnail but I couldn't get thumbnail for other formats.

I tried to use MediaMetaDataRetriever class but nothing happens.

Here is the line where I tried to get my bitmap :

We are in my VideoAdapter class in the getView method. `holder` is my ViewHolder class and `thumbVideo` is my ImageView.

Here is differents lines I tried :

`holder.thumbVideo.setImageBitmap(createVideoThumbnail(m_Context, Uri.parse(m_Video.getM_Preview())));`

`m_Video` is my Video class and the method `getM_Preview()` is getting the link of video thumbnail.

Here is my `createVideoThumbnail(Context context, Uri uri)` method :

```
    public Bitmap createVideoThumbnail(Context context, Uri uri) {
    Bitmap bitmap = null;
    MediaMetadataRetriever retriever = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
    try { 
        retriever.setDataSource(context, uri);
        bitmap = retriever.getFrameAtTime(-1);
    } catch (RuntimeException ex) {
    } finally { 
        try { 
            retriever.release();
        } catch (RuntimeException ex) {
        } 
    } 
    return bitmap;
}
```

I am looking an answer for 4 days. If anybody know how I can do, it'll be helpful

Comment: we have the same problem in getting thumbnails from Streaming Server, did you find a solution?

Comment: I advise you to get thumbnail manually et get picture from the server because I didn't solve it with an other way..

Answer (score 0):

you can try like below

```
       Bitmap thumbnail =ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(mVideoUri.getPath(),
                                            MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND);
        BitmapDrawable  bitmapDrawable = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), thumbnail);
videoView.setBackground(bitmapDrawable);
```